# What is the Biblical basis that through the covenants God has promised to bless his people materially?

Tags: biblical-basis, prosperity-gospel

Some people who teach that Christians can expect to be blessed materially in this life by God base their teachings in the covenants.

What is the Biblical basis that through the covenants God has promised to bless his people materially and financially in this life?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18755/discussion-between-curiousdannii-and-hello).

Comment: This post contains more statements than it does questions. As far as the basic scope of the question goes it seems to be largely the same scope as the other question. Any aspect in which it is different is entirely unclear from the current form. Also your answer would seem to fit on that question nearly as-is, so I see no reason not to treat this as a duplicate. Please repost your answer over on the other question and make any adaptions for it to address that context well.

Comment: Also you should know that @curiousdannii is right about tags. Please do not use tags that do not apply to the scope of your question. Whether or not you intent an answer to mention Abraham, he was not mentioned or even hinted as as part of what you were questioning. Likewise your even in the OT is used in answering this question is _not about_ the OT. Tag taxonomy can be hard at first, so when you do get help in that area it's usually best to let more experienced community members clean things up. Tags aro not a chance to add 5 of whatever you feel like, they are for our local organization.

Comment: @Caleb the tags cd ref. was my choice of 'covenant' which definitely does apply to this question. This question is asking for the whole rationale behind PG, which is definit diff than the other question plus the answer includes diff. info.

Comment: I note the covenant tag disappeared again along with all the other tags, covenant is very pertinent because it is the Abrahamic cov. that carries to the NT through Christ as apostle Paul wrote, PGs based their beliefs on the Abrahamic Covenant and the apostle Pauls writings

Comment: @Hello There are lots of answers that mention the Abrahamic covenant, but only questions that mention covenants should be tagged with the covenant tag. Your **question** does not currently ask for answers relating to covenants, so it shouldn't have the tag. That doesn't mean that your **answer** can't talk about Abraham's covenant. Make sense?

Comment: @curiosdannii  do you mean the question has to contain the word 'covenant' in order for a 'covenant' tag to apply, are you saying that the only tags that can be used have to appear as words in the question?

Comment: when I checked other questions what you have said above is not what occurs.

Comment: @Hello Your question is not _about_ covenants. The fact that you believe the answer to be based on a covenant is irrelevant. Reformed theology sees _everything_ as dependent on covenants, that doesn't mean everything gets that tag. The tags are not for your use as a question asker so much as for the site taxonomy. Please let the community that understands them manage them.

Comment: Also your last edit shows some pretty major miss-understandings about how the site works. If you are still having trouble understanding and want help from the community in explaining why this is a duplicate (and why you should move your answer), please post on [meta].

Comment: @Caleb my reasoning is that the whole PG rationale is based on covenant, you're saying that I have to include the word covenant in the question- I don't know how to go about taking it up in meta, just cl. meta and post the same question there? what does meta have to do with Christianity? maybe I can change the question's content

Comment: @Hello [meta] is the companion site for discussing issues to do with how this site works. If you think this is not a duplicate, you should post a question there giving your reasoning and asking the community to review it and either change it or explain to you why it's fine the way it is. If you don't understand why a tag does not apply, post a question there asking how the tag should be used. Please do not keep editing something in that the community has taken out---if you disagree or don't understand the place to discuss it is on the meta site, not in the body of the question here on main.

Comment: @Hello Why don't you copy your answer to the other question? If you think the other question's answers aren't good enough the best thing to do is to answer it yourself, not make a new question.

Comment: @all, tags are reference pts? someone could click on to find questions/answers on that topic? so question has to be exactly on that topic/tag? not just "about" and including that information? has to be exact?i can't stay online right now, sorry..........

Comment: @Hello If you disagree about the tags you may raise the concern on [meta]. You may not just keep adding the tag back. After being asked not to do so three times now you've gone and done it again so I'm now locking this post from all edits. If you want a different outcome and don't agree with the way it is, **ask about it on meta**!

Answer (score -1):

PG-ers  would say that Jesus and the redemption He bought on the cross was preplanned by the Father, "before the foundation of the earth"  1 Peter 1:20 He was chosen before the creation of the world , Rev 13:8 Aramaic Bible in Plain English "those who are not written in The Book of Life of The Lamb slain before the foundation of the world."

Next they would say that the fall of Adam and Eve ***removed mankind from under the blessing of God, because God had to separate Himself from them because of their sin.***

The Blessing of God left with the glory of God, when this separation occurred, evidenced by God's words on the subject that spell a list of changes that the couple would have to accept under a new environment for them which God called The Curse.   Gen 3:16, 17, 18 Pain, sorrow, loss, blood, sweat, and tears are listed as the curse.

Then PG-ers would point out that Deut. 28 spells out what further curse can be expected if a life of disobedience was walked in.
Moses commanded six leaders from six tribes to stand on Mt Gerizim to pronounce the ‘Blessings’ that would come upon the people for obedience.
The other six leaders from  the remaining six tribes stood upon Mt Ebal and pronounced the 'Curse's for disobedience.

**Deuteronomy 28 lists the ‘Blessings’:**

1. God will set you on high above all the other nations of the earth and all these ‘blessings’ shall come upon you (Deut 28:1-2)  2. You will be ‘blessed’ in the city (Deut 28:3) 3. You will be ‘blessed’ in the field 4. You will have perfect offspring (Deut 28:4)5. Your crops will be ‘blessed’ (prosperity provision) 6. Your cattle will be ‘blessed’ (prosperity provision)7. Your flocks will increase 8. Your baskets and storehouses will be full of good things(Deut 28:58)9. You will be ‘blessed’ in all you undertake Deut 28:68 10. You will have complete victory over all your enemies (poverty sickness disease incl.) (Deut 28:7)  11. Your land will be abundantly fertile and productive 12. You will be established as a holy people unto God (Deut 28:9) 13. You will be a witness and an example to all people on earth vs 10 14. All nations will be afraid of you 15. You will be prosperous in goods in children in stock and in crops in all the land vs 11 16. The Lord will open to you all His good treasure vs 12, 17. The heavens will give you rain in due season in all your land, 18. The Lord will ‘bless’ the work of your hands,19. You will be prosperous enough to lend to many nations and you will ‘not’ need to borrow from them, 20. The Lord shall make you the head and ‘not’ the tail vs 13, 21. You shall be above and never beneath.

**& ‘Curses’:**

'The Curse spelled out in Deut 28: 16 - on 
This is basically the opposite of all the Blessing is described as. Initially, in the garden of Eden, the Curse began, however, scripture above stated shows us that before the earth was created, the 'Lamb was slain from before the beginning of the world.', meaning it was God's plan to keep the curse off of His people by shedding Jesus' blood, and until then, in the OT the blood of animals was shed as a temporary sacrifice, until the sacrifice would manifest.

**The Good News Against the Curse**

At the time of Abraham, God made a promise to Abraham and to his seed, which Paul writes about in the NT in the book of Galatians 3:13, quotrng the exact promise and explaining it.

**Christ Redeemed Us from the Curse**

12However, the Law is not of faith; on the contrary, ----
13Christ redeemed us from the curse of the Law, having become a curse for us---- "-
 14in order that in Christ Jesus the blessing of Abraham might come to the Gentiles, so that we would receive the promise of the Spirit through faith. 
Jesus Came to Redeem Us From the Curse attached to Disobedience to God
Paul writes Christ came to redeem us from the Curse  by becoming a Curse for us, and also, in 2 Cor 5:21 Paul writes that Jesus was made to be sin on our behalf. How could Jesus become sin, if He had none Himself? Jesus chose to become one with sin, the same way He wants us to become one with His rightouesness by faith, just by believing because He said so.' The Lord God laid on Him the iniquity of us all.'is how the Father made Jesus become sin itself. ( from Isaiah 53:6) This was also prefigured by the snake that was lifted up on the pole, a foreglance at Jesus after He became one with sin and was lifted up on the cross for us.

**2 Cor 5: , 21**

21He made Him who knew no sin to be sin on our behalf, so that we might become the righteousness of God in Him.

These are the reasons from scripture the Prosperity Gospel adherents believe support it being God's will to Bless abundantly and prosper us in the New Covenant, because it was always His will, only the fall interrupted it. Jesus becoming the curse for us removes the curse for us, so that we can receive the Blessing spoken about to and upon Abraham, who is our own father of Faith.

PG-ers believe Jesus came to redeem Eden and that He did so at the cross. They believe that the Kingdom of God was present with Jesus on the earth and that the cross made the Kingdom of God accessible to believers on the earth, after Jesus left. The Kingdom of God is  Eden restored now, to PG-ers. They believe it is possible to live in Heaven on the Earth now, or Eden, and they also believe Jesus is coming and will set up a physical Kingdom on the Earth as well. Jesus himself said the Kingdom of God was here, when He was here, so much more so now, post cross and redemption. This Eden on the earth now is accessible by faith and living in repentance, and requires overcoming all that Satan will throw at them, because they believe as well all the scriptures about persecution coming against the child of God, and especially the ones that says greater persecution will come to those who receive '100-fold houses, lands, family, etc.' for Jesus' sake because they gave.

PG-ers are great believers in giving, especially of money, which they call investing in God's kingdom and laying up treasure for themselves in heaven. They especially give to the poor and are known to pick poor areas of cities to provide new furniture, clothing and extra food for the freezers of the most poor they know. (like Jesus did_) They practice giving to each other as a form of love, to include air planes, cars trucks boats, houses cottaqges warehouses full of things, etc.